# Which one is better in calling a function: two times or storing the result in a variable?

Tags: java, performance, variables

I have got this doubt many times, but didn't figure it out the correct soltion. This time I want clear it off. I have situation like

```
1. 
String sNumber="ksadfl.jksadlf";
if(sNumber.lastIndexOf('.')>0)
   //do something
...
...
if(sNumber.lastIndexOf('.')>1)
 //do something
...

2.
int index = sNumber.lastIndexOf('.');
if(index>0)
//do something
...
...
if(index>1)
//do something
...
```

what are the trade offs between first way and second way? which one is better in storing the result in a variable or calling the function two times?

Comment: ofcourse storing a result.

Comment: @siva: If the posted answer has clear your doubts the accept this answer.

Comment: It's actually a better question than what it looks like. Storing something instead of recalculating it seems like an obvious optimization, but there is a point where it actually becomes slower. That point is nowhere in sight in this example, but it is real yet often ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this example, the 2nd form is better (in most plausible situations<sup>1</sup>) from a performance perspective, and (IMO) more readable.

In general, there are a couple of trade-offs to consider:

- Is readability more important than efficiency?
- How much of a "performance hit" is it to call the method twice versus once?

Also, you also need to consider the cases where the method may have side-effects, and whether it may give a different answer on two successive calls.  In those cases, calling the method twice is semantically different to calling it once and storing the result in a temporary variable.

---

<sup>1 - The `index` variable makes the stack frame 1 word larger.  Normally this doesn't matter, but if the code is in a recursive method that gets called in a deeply recursive fashion, that 1 extra word multiplied by a number of nested calls could result in a `StackOverflowError`.</sup>

Comment: +1 for mentioning readability. IMO it is very often (but not always) the most important factor to consider.
Sometimes, if the call in question is "cheap" and you really want to keep the code short then you can save one line by resorting to the second way.

Comment: I just wanted to say that you could avoid the insertion of the index variable in the stack if you declare it as a private member (witch would act as a global variable in this case), with this choice the second option will always be more efficient and won't go on StackOverflow more easily

Comment: @AlessandroRossi - that can be problematic; e.g. if you want to use the variable after the recursive call returns ... you can't.

Comment: @StephenC : you are right. Some of my doubts also cleared.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question only talks about 2 lean `lastIndexOf` calls, there's actually little difference between the two. If it's a remote call via a proxy or something that does a database hit, then storing the method result into a variable would see you some improvement.

[image]

The good thing about calling the method again is that you'll always get the latest value of the index, in case it was manipulated somewhere in the earlier blocks. On most cases, #2 will be the right choice, but for your exact example above, it's #1.

Comment: Good point, but it's better practice in general to keep sNumber immutable. In which case cascading impact isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your doubts are obvious. Your 2nd approach is good and efficient.

Because if, your string variable data is not changing every time then no need to get the index every time. No, need to use `sNumber.lastIndexOf('.')` again and again. Every time when your `lastIndexOf()` function will run , it will take extra time and other resources.

So, its better you use 2nd option which makes your program faster and shorter.

Comment: not always true, the two calls might be optimized into one by the interpreter for you (although I'm not saying that's a reason to use the first method) also, you've only answered the question afew minutes ago, no need to rush the op into accepting it. besides,  a better one might be posted.

Comment: @vikki how that two calls are optimized into one? I think here it is a string `sNumber`, which is immutable, it might be the case. But, as @Ronixus said, what if that string changes in between the two calls? and is it the same case with `someObject` calls?

Comment: @siva that can be checked, granted its not always obvious and therefore not easy for the compiler to check. my point was that in some cases java can be sure that the result of the method will be the same and therefore cache it. however like I said this is unpredictable and not reason enough to go with method 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a classic trade-off between memory usage and CPU usage.

First you have to determine if you want your program to have a small footprint in memory or whether you want it to run fast. Solution 1 will most likely result in the least memory usage (since you are not storing an int), while solution 2 will result in the fastest execution time since you don't have to do the indexOf computation twice.

That being said storing calculations in memory does not always result in the fastest program. Having a small memory footprint often result in fewer cache misses. Cache misses is very often much slower than simply doing the calculation twice.

To get an idea of the importance of minimizing cache misses take a look at [this](http://yaserzt.com/blog/archives/615) post about the performance of list vs. vector in C++. One would expect the list to be much faster than the vector since data doesn't have to be copied around. The list implementation does however have much more random access of data, and therefore a lot more cache misses resulting in vector being alot faster.

In the end I would suggest that you measure the performance of the two solutions and determine which combination of memory and cpu usage you like the most.